# MediaPlayer keep playing even button disabled

Tags: java, android, media-player

I tried most of options avialable on stackoverflow, could you please help me!
I have a button which plays MediaPlayer instance when clicked, but the problem if I click double-click or clicked during playing media it will play two times even i set the button.setEnable(false) and button.setClickable(false), below is the code in Main.java, and I have set in xml android:onClick="playMedia"

```
MediaPlayer playMedia;
private void playGeneric(MediaPlayer mp, int name, Button button) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setClickable(false);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, name);
    mp.start();
    while (mp.isPlaying()) {
    }
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setClickable(false);

}

// play the Media
public void playMedia(View button) {
    playGeneric(Media, R.raw.Media, (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You should have a single (preferably `static`) `MediaPlayer` instance per your activity/service

2- This loop `while (mp.isPlaying())` is extremely bad practice, you just need to listen to the appropriate event

3- Before creating a new `MediaPlayer` instance you have to check that if the current one is not null then stop and release it

To solve your code you can do the following:

1- Let your class implements `OnCompletionListener` and override the method `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` to be notified when the `MediaPlayer` finished and clean the resources (but you need to clean it as well when your activity/service get destroyed)

2-

```
static MediaPlayer playMedia;

private void playGeneric(MediaPlayer mp, int name, Button button) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setClickable(false);
    if(mp !=null){
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, name);
    mp.start();

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release();
    playMedia = null;
    button.setEnabled(true);
    button.setClickable(true);
}
```

Comment: the problem that i have 6 more buttons and each one has it's own Media to play when clicked, how I can make the onCompletion method more Generic.

Comment: You receive an instance of `MediaPlayer` so you can register the same listener for all of them; but be aware that you should **not** have multiple MediaPlayer per your app